# How to update visibility of an UI element in a DataTemplate in GridView

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on an UWP application. Which has a GridView with following structure:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:boolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ExampleItems, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="mDataGridView" ItemClick="mDataGridView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DataTemplate" x:DataType="local:ItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Background="OrangeRed" x:Name="rootPanel">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock" Text="{x:Bind Title,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Subtitle,Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Description,Mode=OneWay}" />
                <ProgressBar Visibility="{x:Bind ShowProgress, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter},Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

And a quite simple corresponding item data class:

```
public class ItemTemplate
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool ShowProgress { get; set; }
}
```

A converter to convert the "ShowProgress" property into Visibility:

```
public class boolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        bool show = (bool)value;
        return show ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
        return visibility.Equals(Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```

The code works fine to display the GridView when the application starts. But if I try to change the the progress bar visibility by changing corresponding "ShowProgress" property when the application is running, the view won't update.

```
ExampleItems[15].ShowProgress = true;
ExampleItems[15].Title = "New Title 15";
```

Any one got any idea for how to change the visibility with x:bind mechanism? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and fire the `PropertyChanged` event whenever property values change.

for E.g :

```
public class ItemTemplate :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _showProgress;
    public bool ShowProgress
    {
        get { return _showProgress; }
        set
        {
            _showProgress = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ShowProgress");
        }
    }


   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
     {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
     }
}
```

For the complete code listing, see the XAML data binding sample.